# jQuery update record only once unless I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using `jQuery` to update `database record`. It updates fine for the first time, but will never update the record again unless the page is reloaded.

I am using `jQuery` because I don't want to refresh the page. My code is shown below. Please how can I amend my code so it will allow user to update record as many times as he wants?

```js
$('body').on('click', '#subForm', function() {
  $.post($("#form_id").attr("action"), $("#form_id").serialize(), function(info) {
    $("#result").html(info);
  });

  clearInput();

  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, "slow");
});

$('body').on('submit', '#form_id', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});

function clearInput() {
  $("#form_id")[0].reset();
}
```

```html
 <div id="result"></div>
<form action="upgrade.php" method="post" id="form_id">
  <select name="item">
    <option><?php echo $item;?></option>
    <?php /* PHP Script */ ?>  
  </select>
  <select name="category">
    <option><?php echo $category;?></option>
    <?php /* PHP Script */ ?>  
  </select>
  <button id="subForm">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why not handle your form submission and prevent default in the same function?

Comment: Where is `#result`? It sounds like you need a delegated event handler somewhere

Comment: @Rory result is above the form. I have just added it.

Comment: I don't know php, but are there any hidden `id` input fields? It might be getting reset when you `.reset()`?

Comment: Yes there is a hidden input field, and am actually using php on another page to submit to database.

Comment: @Oponjous what other page? is the hidden `id` input inside the form you are resetting? Because you are updating a `database record`. You must have a unique identifier for it within the `form_id` form?

Comment: Looking at the documentation for .post(), there doesn't seem to be any way for you to handle errors, so you could have something wrong on the server end and not even know it, right? I'd use .ajax() and check for errors.

Comment: Yes it is within the form am inserting and it is the ID of the item. I first fetch the details of the item including the ID which I made hidden. Then I edit and submit.

Comment: @Brain I don't know jQuery very well. How do I add the error code?

Comment: Use `$.post(url, data, function,(res, status, error){});`

Comment: This code has syntax error.